# accessing truecaller's database

Tags: c++, api

I need help regarding on how I can use truecaller's database. I want to write a c++ program that can access the numbers in the database to check the name of that number. While googling, I found that there is a truecaller API but I don't know how to use it (it seems it's not free and I'm ready to buy a license, but at least I need to test it first). I'm not able to use it. if anyone can provide me any guidelines or steps, I'll be very grateful. And if there is another way (like a web service or something), it'll also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truecaller doesn't provide an API that you could use. If you refer to https://dev.truecaller.com/docs these are just legacy documentation for people who already got access. Truecaller doesn't give out any new access to these APIs.

Source: I work for Truecaller

Comment: how can truecaller or similar such service providers (i know sync.me, which else massive ones?) store personal information about user B by taking it from user A, without permission of user B (permission of A doesn't matter), isn't this a case of privacy infringement?

Comment: @computingfreak : Truecaller asks for call log permission from user.

Comment: Btw I want to know whether that truecaller profile is verified on truecaller or not..any idea how to fetch that? I’m unable to see any variable in TrueProfile corresponding to that..